# People picker field of Infopath hosted on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, people-picker

I have an Infopath form hosted on SharePoint online list, People picker field is not accepting SharePoint groups. In column settings, I have selected Allow People and Groups option.

Any idea or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that**

- The correct mapped `People and Groups` field in **List Setting** Allow selection of: **People and Groups** as shown below

[image]

- In InfoPath side, Make sure that you have set the same setting in control properties

[image]

Comment: On Infopath side, when I got to field properties I only see Data and details tab. I don't see General Tab.

Comment: share what you have as image plese

Comment: http://imgur.com/8j2Okq2

Comment: @Sam this field and group properties, not person and group picker field, try to drag and drop your person and group picker field from fields list in Infopath designer